# onClick add item to array with limit to 3 items with no duplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, duplicates, slice

OnClick the button will add content to an array.

- Limit to have latest 3 clicks
- Put the new content to end of the array, and remove the oldest one (oldest item will drop from array).
- All items jump one step to the left

**Example:**

```
1. If I click on button "Apple", then "Banana" then "Strawberry".
Output will be: ["Apple" , "Banana" , "Strawberry"]
** CORRECT , content jumps to left and drop last one. **

2. If I then click "Apple" it will drop the first item "Banana" and ADD "Apple" to last.
Output will be: ["Banana" , "Strawberry", "Apple"]
** CORRECT , content jumps to left and drop last one. **

3. If I then click "Banana" it will drop the first  item and ADD "Apple" to last.
Output will be: ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Banana"]
** FAIL , content does not jumps to left correct. **

Output should be: ["Strawberry", "Apple", "Banana"]
// "Strawberry" should take place 1 and "Apple" place 2.
```

JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/btcr1yL9/1/

Comment: please post your code into the question. (not the jsfiddle link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this could help.

**UPDATE**

```
var list = [];

$('button').click(function () {
  var fruit = $(this).text();

  var index = list.indexOf(fruit);
  if (index === -1) {
    if (list.length > 2) {
      list.splice(0, 1);
    }
    list.push(fruit);
  } else {
    list.splice(index, 1);
    list.push(fruit);
  }

  console.log(list);
});
```

Comment: This failes too. If i click ["Apple", "Banana", "Strawberry"] then click "Banana", is still same result. In this case it would be ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Banana"]

Comment: @Doodl Just updated my answer. check it and let me know if it's what you need.

Comment: Now all seems to be correct. Items move from right position to left, and drop left (oldest one)! Thx! =)

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem,

```
var list = [];

$('button').click(function() {

  var fruit = $(this).text();
  
  var index = list.findIndex(item => item  === fruit);
  if(index === -1) {
     list.push(fruit);
  } else {
     list.splice(index, 1);
     list.push(fruit);
  }
  if(list.length > 2) {
     list.shift();
  }
  
  console.log(list);

});
```

Fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sabbir_bd/Lh8dso4e/2/).

Comment: VERY CLOSE!  BUT! when click "Apple", then "Banana", then "Strawberry" then "Apple"  then "Banana", The order in array failes. I get ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Banana"], but correct would be ["Strawberry", "Apple", "Banana"]. Everything should jump one step to left.

Comment: Updated the link please check.

Comment: Both you and @baymax has solved same thing in different solutions =) Thx!